# WinRT - XAML FlipView control - unusual new bahavior

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I wonder if someone can help me with the FlipView control in windows 8. I have an app that uses a FlipView . Everything was working fine until a recent windows 8 update, and now the FlipView flips 'twice' in certain circumstances.

Here is some example XAML that reproduces the error:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <FlipView >
        <Grid Height="762" Background="#FF29AA29">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="762" Background="#FF192780">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="762" Background="Green">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="762" Background="Orange">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="762" Background="Blue">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="762" Background="Red">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="6" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Height="762" Background="Yellow">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="7" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                       Foreground="Black" FontSize="96"/>
        </Grid>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

As you can see its a very simple example with numbered grids inside the FlipView.

Now, if you click on the forward or back flip buttons (slightly greyed out buttons on left and right sides) WITHOUT moving the mouse to a different location (i.e. move the mouse over the forward button and click multiple times without moving the mouse again) it will flip 1,2,4,6,7 (see numbers in my xaml).

If however you move the mouse slightly between clicks you get the correct behaviour (1,2,3,4,5,6,7).

This error exists in both local machine and emulator mode.

It doesn't happen when you use the finger drag method in the emulator to flip.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the Windows 8 update I downloaded screwed the driver for my touchpad, and the issue is purely driver related - very weird though